# Calculating Aggregates Using Table Variables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm updating some stored procedures from SQL Server 2000 to 2008. After making the required syntactical changes, everything is working nicely except for one item that works as desired in 2000 but not in 2008. Here's a greatly simplified reproducible statement of my issue.

I have a table with the following data:

[image: Table_1]

I am using the following stored procedure to extract data and calculate an aggregate count:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1 

AS
DECLARE @tablevar AS TABLE (
   userid NCHAR(4),
   foo NCHAR(2),
   bar NCHAR(2),
   total INT,
   PRIMARY KEY (userid, foo, bar)
)

INSERT INTO @tablevar (userid, foo, bar)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.userid, t1.foo, t1.bar
FROM Table_1 t1
GROUP BY UserID, Foo, Bar

UPDATE @tablevar
SET total =
    (SELECT COUNT(logid) 
     FROM Table_1 t1
     WHERE t1.UserID = UserID and
           t1.Foo = Foo and 
           t1.Bar = Bar)

SELECT * FROM @tablevar
RETURN
GO
```

This produces the following results:

[image: Result Set]

When using SQL Server 2000 the entries in the `total` column were [2, 1, 1, 1], which is the intended result. I'm assuming I'm missing something incredibly obvious here, but I can't quite seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: Where is `UserID,Foo and Bar` coming from? (in your update statement)

Comment: The intent is to use the values from the table variable (i.e. for each row in the table variable, calculate the number of rows in Table_1 with the same values for UserID, Foo, and Bar). I actually tried fully qualifying the right sides of those WHERE clauses and the result was the same. Not sure if that answers your question - let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have to use the table variable, fill it like this:

```
INSERT INTO @tablevar (userid, foo, bar, total)
SELECT userid, foo, bar, count(1) as total
FROM Table_1
GROUP BY userid, foo, bar
```

Comment: There are actually a series of updates that the real procedure does, which does require the use of a table variable. I'll update the question to mention that.

Comment: Updated to reflect need for table variable.